# LibGDX wait for input

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using LibGDX to create an app. My InputHandler class implements InputProcessor and I have a Game class that contains the loop. I want to add in the game loop a "wait for user input" before continuing looping. How would I go about this?

Comment: Read a bit more about event driven programming. Libgdx has plenty of examples around this issue. Did you check any of them ?

Comment: Thanks! That was the key words I was looking for to do more research on my own.